# Iterating through one dict of size n vs two dicts of size n/2

Tags: python, performance, hashmap, big-o

Implementing a bijective map. Internally representing it using dictionary(s).

Is there a performance difference between iterating through a dictionary of size n and iterating through two dictionaries of size n/2?

Option 1:

```py
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 1: 'A', 2: 'B'}

if some_key in d:
    ...
```

Option 2:

```py
d1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
d2 = {1: 'A', 2: 'B'}

if some_key in d1 or some_key in d2:
    ...
```

While both options would involve the same number of iterations, my concern is that there may be some auxiliary operations happening before each `__contains__()` is invoked by the `in` keyword, resulting in the second option being slightly worse as it has two of them.

Are they equivalent?

Comment: Supposedly, running the iteration parallelly (not concurrently) would make it more performant I would say.

Comment: If most of your keys will be found in `d1` you might find it faster because it won't have to check `d2`.

Comment: Option 2 has the advantage that keys and vals don't have to be "disjoint"

Comment: In the case of your data, Option 2 has the advantage that dicts with all string keys have been optimized in CPython, Option 1 won't get that optimization.

Comment: @wim Could you elaborate on your "disjoint" comment? Wouldn't option 2 be "disjoint" since both dictionaries are separate, while option 1 has both dictionaries combined into one? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I mean that option 1 usage prohibits the case where `x` happens to be both a key and a value. Your example data doesn't have that possibility, but you'd want to make sure the real data also doesn't have that possibility because the failure mode is _silent_ (no exception raised).

Comment: @wim ah, I actually want that to be the case as I'm implementing a bijective map, so key-values need to be one-to-one.

Comment: @MichaelMoreno I recommend using [`bidict`](https://bidict.readthedocs.io/en/main/) in that case, it's specifically designed for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

First, you ask about `iterating` but it's not the thing that is happening while using `in`. To answer that question we need to dig into how dictionaries works in python.

There actually were few significant changes of how they are implemented but their internals are based on the hash map with different colision resolution methods (see quite detailed explanation [here](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-10-how-python-dictionaries-work/)). In most cases size of the dict has very small impact on time performance and we need constant number of checks to find an element (we say it's O(1) in average case, however single `in` can indeed check all keys)

Saying that, it's like one check vs two checks and I would bet that two dict version is slower.

Comment: I think the dict was *always* based on a hashmap, any changes are only in the implementation details.

Comment: It is not "constant number of checks to find an element". It is amortized average case _O(1)_, which means something very different.

Comment: That's true actually, I wanted to write about colisions but searched for some source.

Comment: @wim I just used more human language - **in most cases**

Comment: You can never say the number of checks is "constant", no matter how sparse you keep the arrays it will always be variable, due to possibilities of hash collision handling.

Comment: But that's exactly what O(1) means - constant. Constant isn't 1 or 5, constant in this terminology means that size of the structure doesn't affect time of doing such operation.

Comment: Hmm, _not exactly_. We're splitting hairs now, but it doesn't mean that the number of checks or runtime is constant. It means that the number of checks or runtime _can be bounded above by a constant_. The actual number of checks or runtime may still vary wildly as n changes, big O is only describing the asymptotic behavior.